# Wildfly 13 JMX using SSL

Tags: ssl, wildfly, jmx

I am using Wildfly 13 standalone with JMX enabled:

```
<remoting-connector/>
```

The management interface is going through https:

```
<management-interfaces>
  <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
    <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
      <socket-binding https="management-https"/>
```

SSL is set up:

```
<security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
  <server-identities>
    <ssl>
      <keystore path=.../>
    </ssl>
  </server-identities>
```

When I start JConsole and try to connect on

```
service:jmx:remote+http://localhost:9993
```

I don't get connection.

When I revert the binding to http I can connect to `service:jmx:remote+http://localhost:9990`

Is it possible to have JMX with SSL using the `remote+http` protocol?

Thanks,

--Ivo

Answer (score 0):

It should be `service:jmx:remote+https://<server>:9993`